# How to prevent an option from being displayed by Options?

Tags: image, options

```
Options[image]
```

This gives a list:

> ```
> {ColorSpace -> 
>    ColorProfileData[ ...], Interleaving -> True, MetaInformation -> {"Something"}}
> ```

I can update the values like:

```
Image[image, MetaInformation-> {"updated value"->"something"}]
```

The question is how can I prevent `MetaInformation` from being displayed by `Options` under some condition?

Comment: Under what condition? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMA seems to treat images as atoms, so pattern matching inside an Image object appears difficult. How about splitting the image into data, type and options and replacing your option according to some rule:

```
ClearAll[replaceImageOptions];
replaceImageOptions[image_, rule_] := Module[{type, data, opts},
    type = ImageType[image];
    data = ImageData[image, type];
    opts = Options[image];
    Image[data, type, opts /. rule]
];

image = Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Amanita_muscaria_%28fly_agaric%29.JPG"];

image2 = replaceImageOptions[image, (MetaInformation -> _) -> Nothing];

Options[image]
(* {ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True, MetaInformation -> ... } *)

Options[image2]
(* {ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True} *)
```

EDIT: In case you're just interested in suppressing `MetaInformation` from the output of `Options` and don't want to change anything in the image object, you could simply use

```
Options[image] /. (MetaInformation -> _) -> Nothing
```